# EF 5 - Model First, How to update DB Schema without dropping database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing in MVC 4, EF 5.0

Model First development - how do I 'easily' get the DB schema to update, without having to drop the database / erase any data?

e.g. I have a Customer table. In this table, we capture name, surname, email address. I now want to collect the telephone number, so I change the model and get EF to update the database schema.

Visual studio 2012 referrs me to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269, however this looks like chinese to me.

They talk about running an NUGET package called code first migrations. Does this functionality not come packaged automatically with VS2012?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Database migrations is what you are looking for. Both automatic and specified in code - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-PL/data/jj591621

Comment: So does this need to be done EVERY time I make a change? Using DB first, you can just build your database, then auto update edmx file. Just wondering, because this seems like a real pain in the ass - or am I missing something.

Comment: During development of first version of your application you can probably regenerate database after every change. But after you go to production migrations are the only way to go. This isn't specific to EF.

Comment: @Gravy - DB first is easy because YOU are doing the hard part (migrating the database).  Doing this reliably is not a trivial task, because it must take many factors into account, thus doing it the other way around is significantly more difficult and requires a lot more process.  It should be noted that DB First doesn't always work reliably either.  Many times it doesn't update things properly, and your only recourse is to manually update it, or delete and re-add the objects.

Comment: Thanks, but tell me something quickly... Does this not mean that EF code first simply is not mature enough? What happened to the whole 'Agile Developent Process' which advocates incremental updates. Does this mean that for EVERY incremental update, we need to double our code to ensure that the db is in sync with the model?

Comment: I don't know what Mystere Man is talking about. Can you share some details? Gravy it doesn't matter if you are using EF or custom SQL in your custom Data access layer. You will have to write migrations either in SQL or in code.